# AspNet Identity ApplicationUser with subtype-specific fields

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have a ASP.NET MVC application which uses ASP.NET Identity. I have 3 roles for my application:

- Student
- Author
- Admin

Those 3 profiles have various fields to persist, so Student role could have X number of fields, Author role, Y number of fields and Admin role, Z number of fields, all unrelated to each other. Problem is that I cannot think a way to make an elegant design.

Here is what I have tried/though so far:

First I though of creating 3 different classes (for each role), so essentially I'm going to have Student, Author and Admin table, which have an 1:1 relationship with ApplicationUser table, but this is not a clean solution at all.

This is what I've implemented at the moment. I have an ApplicationUser class (table) which holds all the common fields of these three roles.
For each of them I have created a class (table) having a 1:1 relationship with ApplicationUser (which acts as "base" class (table))

Another solution I came up was to persist those data on a schema-less storage (for example Table Storage) with PartitionKey the ApplicationUser.Id and RowKey the RoleId, so I can CRUD each entity with ease. Although this might help, this approach could lead to maintain 2 different datasources, which is not what I am looking for.

Any suggestion on clean design for this?

**UPDATE**

From research I get that a model inheritance/supertype-subtype association is probably a good way to go. Especially going with the one table implementation seems good on performance also.
For example:

- Create an ApplicationUser table, which contains all fields (common and subtype-specific)
- 3 additional views for Student, Author and Admin.

Could lead to many `null` values for subtype-specific fields, but seems like a good workaround. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Can a student ever be an author, or an author an admin, or an admin a student?

Comment: @Erresen A student will never have elevated privileges. An author can be upgraded to an admin role. Admin will remain admin. So essentially, only authors can become admins (if an admin adds them as one).

Comment: Is there any commonality between the fields of a student, author, and admin (or between any two of the three)? If not, then I'd just use three separate tables (otherwise you will potentially lose data if you upgrade an author to an admin and then later downgrade them). If there is any commonality I'd put those fields either in ApplicationUser or another "base" table and then have additional tables for any class-specific fields.

Comment: @technophileThat is exactly what I've done now. I filtered out the common fields and all of them reside in ApplicationUser table.
Student, Author and Admin have only their specific fields. I'll update the question so this can be clear. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

I think your approach is quite good. An alternative could be to use asp.net Identity's UserClaims like approach.

In this approach you don't need to have specific fields for each role but a table with 4 columns in which you are going to store

- user's FK
- attribute's data type
- attribute's name
- attribute's value

---

```
---------------------------------
| FK |  Type  | Name | Value    |
---------------------------------
| 1  | string | name | John Doe |
---------------------------------
| 1  |  int   | age  |    30    |
---------------------------------
```

Below you can see an example of what a controller's action could accept as parameter (I made the assumption that name and age is fields that you need only for a Student).

```
{
  id:1, 
  updatedOn : '2016-01-01 00:01', 
  role:'Student', 
  extraFields : {
                  name:'John Doe', 
                  age : 30}
}
```